# How to remove comma in a value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem in removing a comma in a value using Vue.js. Following is my code:

```
displayValue(){
    var displayValue = this.value;
    console.log(displayValue);
    if(displayvalue has comma){
        displayvalue = displayvalue(remove comma)
    }
}
```

I've tried using `indexOF()` but it's not working.

Before `.replace`:
[image]

After`.replace`:
[image]

Comment: Is the comma for a numeric value's thousands separator? Be careful - in some regions comma is used as a decimal separator and dot is used for thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `,` using `replace`

```
displayValue(){
    var displayValue = this.value || ""; //check if this.value is null
    displayValue = String(displayValue).replace(/,/g, ""); //replace ,
}
```

Comment: It throws `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: displayValue.replace is not a function"` same error with certainperformance.

Comment: Please share the output of `console.log(displayValue)`

Comment: Updated my question with snipped result.

Comment: try `displayValue = String(displayValue).replace(/,/g, "");`

Comment: Thanks gurvinder372, maybe you can edit your answer so that I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @ramedju You still haven't shared the output of `console.log(displayValue)`, we need to know what is the type of this object. `console.log(displayValue, typeof displayValue)`

Comment: @ramedju Edited.

Comment: Last one, can I add `.00` after the value?

Comment: Yes,  `displayValue = displayValue + ".00";`, but check if there isn't already a decimal in the displayValue.

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Use `includes`, `displayValue.includes(".") `...read about `includes`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (displayvalue.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
  displayvalue = displayvalue.replace(/,/g, '');
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but is not working. Throws an error `.includes is not a function ....` Thanks.

Comment: You must be using an old browser (which is not recommended for web development). Edited answer